# How can Fopen read png files in php

Tags: php, fopen

I was working on something and I needed the data out of a png file and I can only use PHP. Don't ask why just give me the answer lol

Comment: Define "data" - What exactly is the data you need?

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose below is your image.

[image]

You have to define its url in a variable using the below line

```
$image = 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';
```

after that you can use file_get_content function to get data/content of image.

```
$image_content = file_get_contents($image);
```

also, if you want to convert it into base64 string, you can use base64_encode function.

```
$image_base64Data = base64_encode($image_content);
```

Whole Code will be ......

```
<?php
$image = 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';
$image_content = file_get_contents($image);
$image_base64Data = base64_encode($image_content);
?>
```